# How can I check if the app has switched back to my web view?

Tags: webview, android-webview

I have a web-view and I want to detect when a user has switched to another app and returned. Is there a JavaScript I can hook onto, so I can know when to refresh the web view with new data?

Answer (score 0):

`window.onblur` and `window.onfocus` (or `window.addEventListener`).